# Entity Manager creating duplicate entry

Tags: jpa, ejb-3.0

I am using JPA and trying to create entry into databasse. But when the following code is executed the it create the two row of same record. I also saw the hibernate query but did not find any two insert statement into query. 
There is only a one update statement nothing else.

Spent couple of hours but still not able to figure out the root cause of this issue.

```
public List<AddressEntity> saveAssignAddress(List<AddressEntity> addresses, Long tId){
List<AddressEntity> newAddresses = new ArrayList<AddressEntity>();
    System.out.println("addresses" + addresses.size());
for(AddressEntity address: addresses){
    if(address.getAssignmentId() == null || address.getAssignmentId().intValue() <= 0){
        address.setAssignmentId(getAssignID(tId));
    }
    newAddresses.add(em.merge(address));
}
return addresses;
}
```

Could someone help to resolve this issue.

Comment: You have created 'newAddresses' object and adding it the address objects, but I don't see you are using it anywhere. Can you remove that and also once this method return addresses object does the caller save that again?.

Comment: I tried few cases here. Originally i was return newAddresses, then try to return addresses but both the test case lead same issue.

Comment: There is one more point, i debug this code and found in list there is always one instance of AddressEntity. First time there is not record into database, Should i have been used persist for insert and merge for edit. Because this is working for me.

Comment: If you know it new entity call `persist` else call `merge`, although both will insert the row if the entity doesn't already exist.